# Using std::map in C++ to find the number of keys in the map that are less than a given key

Tags: c++

Given an ordered map (or set) `std::map`in C++, I wish to find the *number of keys* in the map in that are less than or equal to a given key.

As an initial attempt, I can use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` to find an iterator pointing to the predecessor/successor of a key, but would this iterator help me get the number of keys?

Comment: `std::map` does not have an efficient way to count it. Just iterate over the map until you find the key.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated:**

std::map instances are always sorted and basic enumerations are in ascending key order.  You can use the `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` functions directly off the map class itself and combo that with `std::distance`.

So for any map, `m` where you want to count the number of keys in the map that are `<=k`, then this will suffice.

```
auto itor = m.upper_bound(k);
size_t count = std::distance(m.begin(), itor);
```

**Original answer:**

```
int count = 0;
for (const auto &p : m)
{
   if (p.first <= k)
   {
       count++;
   }
   else 
   {
       break;
   }
       
}
```

Comment: Is `std::distance` itself going to be O(lg n)? That's a free function that isn't able to take any advantage of `std::map` internals, and according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) the complexity is linear.

Comment: @NathanPierson - oh you might be right. It's kind of hard to measure distance in a binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

is there an issue with:

```
count = 0;

for (const auto iter = _map.begin(); iter != _map.end(); iter++){

    if (iter->first <= given_key ){
        count++;
    }
}
std::cout << "number of keys less than or equal to given key: " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: You should at least `break;` when you encounter the first key `> given_key`

Answer (score 0):

The data in `std::map`, yes you can use that iterator returned by `std::upper_bound` or `std::lower_bound` to get the number of keys smaller or larger than key by using `std::distance`

```
std::map<int, int> data {
    {1,2},
    {2,3},
    {3,4},
    {4,5}
};

auto iter = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 4, [](std::pair<int,int> a, int b){
    return a.first < b;
});
std::cout << std::distance(data.begin(), iter);
```

Comment: Actually you do not have to use, std::lower_bound or std::upper_bound, std::map, provides its own implementation.